Autogen: Having an agent dynamically decide to which other agent to talk to
Example: I want to have a human user (represented by a UserProxy instance) having a multiturn conversation with an AssistantAgent (main_agent) to solve some complex task. During the conversation the assistant dynamically decides to have 1:1 conversations with other specialized helper Agents. For example the task might be do create some document about a specific topic and one helper agent would know how to do web-research (research_helper) and the other how to create diagrams (diagram_helper). The main Assistant would from time to time have ad hoc conversations with these helpers asking them to perform some task (these might be multiturn conversations).
That means for each turn the assistant would have to dynamically decide if to send a message to the user or any of the helpers.
How to implement this communication pattern?
I looked into group chats, nested chats and SocietyOfMindAgent but so far don't see how to solve problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
